# How to avoid shared bundle folders during deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

We are using capistrano to deploy our rails app and the dev / production version of the app uses the shared/bundle folder. Is there a way to prevent creation of shared/bundle and ask capistrano to use individual gemsets across different stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would setting a `bundle_dir` work for you?

```
set :bundle_dir, "/my/bundle/path"
```

I think by default it is set to:

```
set :bundle_dir, File.join(fetch(:shared_path), 'bundle')
```

Comment: no it wouldn't, we are having issues since multiple environments are sharing the same bundle. I would prefer using individual rvm gemsets not sure how to integrate this using capistrano.

Answer (score 1):

When you say stages, do you mean that you have different environments on the same box, and are using capistrano/multistage?

If so, giving your application a different name for each stage will separate the shared directory.

In deploy/development.rb

```
set :application, "myapp-dev"
```

In deploy/production.rb

```
set :application, "myapp-prod"
```

Comment: yes we have, but both of them are using the same shared bundle which is the source of the problem.

Comment: Set a different bundle_dir parameter in the development and production capistrano multistage config files.